# Random Number without repetition

Tags: .net, vb.net, loops

I have been trying to generate a random number between X and Y without repetition. All the outputs are 0s.

What is the error in the following code? Using the `Loop While`, it works but I want to know what is the problem with the `Loop Until` code.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim X, Y, temp, difference, rNumbers(19) As Integer
    Dim Exist As Boolean = False
    Dim rndm As New System.Random
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the value of X") : X = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the value of Y") : Y = Console.ReadLine()
    If Y < X Then
        temp = X
        X = Y
        Y = temp
    End If
    difference = Y - X
    If difference < 20 Then
        Console.WriteLine("Error, try again! The difference between X and Y must be greater than 20")
        Main()
    Else
        For Count = 0 To 19
            Do
                temp = rndm.Next(X, Y)
                Exist = False
                For Count_2 As Integer = 0 To Count
                    If temp = rNumbers(Count_2) Then
                        Exist = True
                    End If
                Next
            Loop Until Exist = False
            Console.WriteLine(rNumbers(Count))
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Start by turning on Option Strict.  Your RNG should be `rndm.Next(X, Y+1)`.  I cant see where you are ever storing a value to `rNumbers`. Creating an array of values from X to Y and shuffling them would be easier.

Comment: I agree with @Plutonix, better option is to create a list. Something like `Dim numbers = Enumerable.Range(X, ((Y - X) + 1)).OrderBy(Function(i) Guid.NewGuid.ToString()).ToList()` You can emit `ToList` if you prefer to work with an enumerator.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions but this is an exam question which does not allow the use of enumerators.

Comment: you have another error: you prompt the user for a range *greater than* 20, but then your loop is setup for only 20.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Please, no. That’s simply not a good way of shuffling numbers. I’ll grant that it’s a cute trick but it has terrible statistical properties, is inefficient, and there’s no reason at all to choose it over a proper shuffle algorithm. And finally, the `ToString()` call is unnecessary and makes no sense here: `Guid`s are comparable.

Comment: Then add `rNumbers(Count) = temp` before you write to the console window. And if you ever plan to generate the value of `Y` change it to `rndm.Next(X, Y+1)` as the last parameter is exclusive.

Comment: @KonradRudolph do you have any links which have tested things like that or `OrderBy( f(x) rnd.Next())`?  I'm curious because docs for things like clinical studies often have to verify the random picker is unbiased.  Using Fisher-Yates, thats all you usually have to say....

Comment: @Plutonix Using `rnd.Next()` instead of `Guid.NewGuid` is barely better here. Use a proper shuffle (Fisher–Yates is fine).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Sure, that why I said *"something like"*. I was suggesting a concept rather than a complete solution. Next time I'll provide and example using  TrySZBinarySearch.

Comment: @KonradRudolph BTW, OP is looking for a simple solution... ;)

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå - There is no guarantee that `Guid.NewGuid` is random at all. It shouldn't be used as a RNG.

Comment: @Enigmativity Well aren't you a treat. We're discussing *"Random Number **without repetition**"*. I dear you to explain how using `Guid` as a SORT key will change the items in the state machine.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå - My comment was with regard to using it in `.OrderBy(Function(i) Guid.NewGuid.ToString())`. `Guid`'s aren't guaranteed to be random and shouldn't be used as if they were.

Comment: @Enigmativity What do you mean by *"aren't guaranteed to be random*"? Are you implying that in some circumstances it will always be repetitive and/or sequential? Or do you mean [aren't guaranteed to be unique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29)? Anyway, I'll be happy to see you propose an indeterministic solution here in the comments ;)

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå - Simply that the bits that make up a `Guid` are not guaranteed to be random. From Eric Lippert's blog: "Many people seem to be of the mistaken belief that GUIDs are a source of randomness, when in fact they are only guaranteed to be a source of uniqueness."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I am C# developer and I have to convert your code into C# to understand the complete logic, but I am certain there's no reason this code will work as expected, let me list few issues:

1. Where are the values filled in the `int[] rNumbers`, I don't see it getting populated post initialization, so it will always contain zero and you are printing the values from same array, which are always 0, therefore cannot expect any other result
2. Values of `X, Y`are entered by the user and they need to have a gap of 20, now in the `do-while` loop, value `temp` which is random number generated between `X, Y` is compared for values in the `int[] rNumbers` and then only it will proceed in the `while loop` further, but since comparison is only with value 0 in `rNumbers` array, so it will mostly never have the `do-while` loop executed beyond the first `do`
3. Now Random Number, `System.Random` is a pseudo random number class, which will never generate a true random number, check the following by Jon Skeet:

[True Random Number Generator](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx)

It use `System.Cryptography` to generate the true random number

Therefore you need make these important changes, to expect the relevant result

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm works now.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim X, Y, temp, difference, rNumbers(19), tempo As Integer
    Dim Exist As Boolean
    Dim rndm As New System.Random
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the value of X") : X = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the value of Y") : Y = Console.ReadLine()
    If Y < X Then
        temp = X
        X = Y
        Y = temp
    End If
    difference = Y - X
    If difference < 20 Then
        Console.WriteLine("Error, try again! The difference between X and Y must be greater than 20")
        Main()
    Else
        For Count = 0 To 19
            Do
                Exist = False
                tempo = rndm.Next(X, Y)
                For Count_2 As Integer = 0 To Count
                    If rNumbers(Count_2) = tempo Then
                        Exist = True
                    End If
                Next
            Loop Until Exist = False
            rNumbers(Count) = tempo
            Console.WriteLine(rNumbers(Count))
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```